# gcc: separate code and data in custom sections

Tags: gcc, sections

I have a software, which is being migrated from another toolchain to gcc (`arm-none-eabi toolchain`). In the software there are a few custom defined sections in order to structure data / code, use different memory components.

With the gcc toolchain I have a linker script file with the custom sections. With the old toolchain I could just use `#pragma section` for a block of code and data or for the whole file. The compiler internally separated such `#pragma section` blocks in the corresponding sections for code, data, rodata and bss using the given section name. 
With gcc I have only two options:

1. add `__attribute__((section(""))` to each variable / function
2. add the whole file into the section using the linker script file

My problem is, that I now have about 300 files that must be processed and mapped to a specific section, while the code / data separation is kept. The files contain both data and code. 
So If I map the file using the linker script, then all data and code will be mapped to this particular section, no code and data separation.
If I add the `__attribute__` keyword to each variable / function it will take days to accomplish this.

Is there a way to tell the gcc to map the whole file / whole block to a particular section with automatically separation of data and code? Let's say the section name is "mysection", I want to map a whole file to "mysection" and gcc should automatically do the following:

- add uninitalized variables to "mysection.bss"
- initialized data to "mysection.data"
- readonly data to "mysection.rodata"
- code to "mysection.text"

gcc is able to do this for the standard sections.

Comment: With the absence of `#pragma section` or a dedicated compiler flag, I'm not sure there's a way to achieve this (I hope I'm wrong)

Comment: You could write a script to scan your code for pragmas and attach appropriate attributes to functions which follow them.

Comment: regex! use regex!

Answer (score 0):

You can complement compilation commands in your Makefile with calls to `objcopy`:

```
for s in .bss .data .rodata .text; do
  objcopy --rename-section $s=mysection$s file.o
done
```